# CKEditor inserts <br /> twice on keypress enter

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

With ckeditor I always get two `<br />` tags when I press enter. I want to keep the line break tags, but I don't want to insert them twice.

My configuration for the enter key in the config.js:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

How can I make CKEditor only insert it once?

EDIT:
Right now I am solving it with css line-height property. Any more elegant solution would be great.

Comment: Can you create a sample showing that one *Enter* press inserts two `<br>`s? That's not a normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR to CKEDITOR.ENTER_P

By default paragraphs are treated as 2 lines (because of the margin).

What you need to do is set it back to the default settings and change your p tag CSS to remove the margins so it allows it to be on one line.

Comment: `ENTER_P` is the default behavior. I'm quite sure OP does not want p's as he changed the behavior

Comment: Actually no, Paragraphs are treated as two lines. What he needs to do is leave it at default and remove the margin from the paragraph

Comment: `I want to keep the line break tags`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess I will just have to deal with <p> tags instead of <br />